# How to load Plist file in Cocos2dx v3.9

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.x

I am developing one game using Cocos2d-x 3.9. I tried to load the `plist` file in my game with following code.

But the size of data is 0. It returns no data.

How can I load `plist`? `CCDictionary` was deprecated in Cocos2d-x v3.9

```
ValueMap data;
std::string path = FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename("my.plist");
data = FileUtils::getInstance()->getValueMapFromFile(path);
```